# Почему именно такой падеж?

Tags: согласование, падежи, род, одушевленность

С чем связано утверждения, что падеж у слова именительный, а не винительный, если форм слов явно не хватает, для разделения падежей. Именительный - что? винительный - тоже что? Если вопрос один, почему разные падежи? Так может и нет такого падежа у слов 2-ого склонения неодушевленных и у 2-ого склонения одушевленных?

2-е склонение неодуш. падежи:

стул - стула - стул

дерево - дерева - дерево

2-е скл. одуш падежи:

кот - кота - кота

Предложения со словами в падеже:

В комнате стоит стул - какой падеж: винительный или именительный? Может быть тут не хватает синтаксического знака, например - "в комнате (он) стоит: стул". Замечу, что "стоит стул" без уточнения места практически не употребляется. И также, ведь это реверсивная конструкция предложения, первым идет подлежащее: в комнате стул стоит - так ведь не говорят! Зато - "в комнате кот спит", - вполне себе предложение. То есть моё предположение, что неодушевленные предметы не имеют именительного падежа, за исключением некоторых сказочных мотивов когда: У Лукоморья - Дуб *зеленеет. Дуб тут одушевленное, а если бы конструкция была: У Лукоморья зеленеет: дуб. То можно было бы говорить о неодушевленности. Также с котом: кот спит - одушевленное; спит кот - неодушевленное, кот в винительном падеже, кот неживой объект. То есть есть разница в положении слов: кот спит в гараже - кот-одушевленное, в гараже спит кот - неодушевленное.

Отсюда спрашивается, почему подход к выбору падежа именно такой и не учитывает расположение подлежащего относительно глагола. Хотя для ряда склонений расположение существительного относительно глагола может говорить о явной смене падежа:

Мать любит дочь. И.п глагол в.п.

- А он кого любит? - Любит мать. - винительный падеж. Причем подлежащее третьего склонения не получается поставить после глагола. Вывод - подлежащее идёт раньше сказуемого.

Вопрос, если существительное стоит после сказуемого, на основании чего оно считается подлежащим и именительным падежом, если форма падежа совпадает с винительным, а расположение так же не отражает того, что это подлежащее.

Или еще: разрушается дом. Разрушается что? - дом. Дом - винительный падеж?

Дом разрушается. Кто - Дом - и.п., Дом что делает? разрушается. Дом тут одушевленное и именительный падеж.

Человек бежит -  Человек - и.п.
Виден бегущий человек. Виден кто - бегущий. а слово человек - неодушевленное зависимое в винительном падеже. Сравнить вопросы: он кто - человек? / он что - человек?

То есть если сходить из того, что вопрос кто? задается про одушевленный объект, а вопрос что? задается про неодушевленный объект, то человек может быть как одушевленным, так и неодушевленным. Однако, из этого вывода следует, что место расположения существительного относительно глагола может менять его одушевленность. Человек может быть как одушевленным, так и неодушевленным(понятием) в зависимости от места или вопроса который к нему задают.

Что если форма слова отражает миграцию от одушевленного действующего лица, к неодушевленному

....................................................................

Теперь про родительный падеж с которым тоже сложности в виду совпадения формы, что такое родительный падеж?

Возможно выделю отдельным вопросом, потому что тут еще большая чехарда:

Вот есть слово дед - именительный падеж. Деда - родительный падеж. Тогда почему баба - это именительный падеж, а не родительный?

Что, если слова 1 склонения(которые считаются таковыми), это ветки женского уже рода, в начальной форме употребляемые в родительном падеже? Я еще подумаю над этим странным предположением и напишу подробнее попозже)

Или вот есть слово:

ЛИС. Форма женского рода ЛИСа совпадает с родительным падежом мужской формы слова, но ударение смещается на окончание.

Хотя если взять другую пару слов - СУПРУГ-СУПРУГа, то там даже смещения ударения не происходит. Так как отличить родительную форму мужского рода, от именительного падежа женского рода? или это одно и тоже?

Почему это проблема: дело в том, что в русском языке возможны безличные(а точнее бессубъектные) предложения, когда глагол есть, причем по форме глагола можно предположить о существовании субъекта действия, но явного употребления может и не быть.

Светает. Спишь? Сплю. Тоже, спала. - то есть по глаголу уже зачастую можно понять о каком лице или роде идет речь, поэтому глагол является самодостаточным для формирования фразы, но не безличной (потому что род также может быть отражён в форме глагола), а бессубъектной.

Comment: Я дам пояснение к тем неточностям, которые заметила. 1. Значение падежей определяется на уровне словосочетаний: главное  слово (глагол) + зависимое слово (сущ.) + предлог (если есть). 2. И.п. (начальную форму слова) сложно спутать с другим падежом: это подлежащее, именное сказуемое или приложение к подлежащему. 3. В предложении определяются предикативная основа и исходные словосочетания, на осове которых оно построено. 4. Падеж имеет грам. значение и грам. форму (падежные окончания). 5. Надо учитывать синонимию окончаний: одно окончание может выражать значения разных падежей.

Comment: Иногда кажется, что И.п. сложно отличить от В.п. в предложении: Мать любит дочь. Это прямой порядок слов. Представить реальную ситуацию с обратным порядком затруднительно. Но в общем случае инверсию надо учитывать и сначала сделать грамматический разбор, а потом определять падежи для подлежащего (И.п.) и дополнения (В.п.).  Падеж нельзя однозначно определить по форме слова ввиду синонимии окончаний.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо. Давайте за основу возьмет: мать любит дочь. кто - мать, что делает любит, любит что - дочь. Мать - именительный падеж. То есть именительный падеж имеет место быть, когда существительное употреблено до глагола и зависимых слов?

Comment: @Sharon про пункты: 2 - у меня путаются, 3 - в русском языке не все предложения предикативные, а также есть личные, но бессубъектные и с предикативностью я не уверен, если было все предикативно, то порядок бы слов не нарушался. 4. форма слов совпадает, и(!) вопросы совпадают. 5. причина синонимии не ясна: синонимия зависит от одушевленности, а в первом склонении синонимии нет, хотя, если только считать и.п. 1 склонения чистым именительным падежом, а не родительным второго склонения. 1 и 6?. чем обусловлено взаимное расположение слов(относительно глагола) и как это влияет на выбор падежа?

Comment: @Sharon 7. и к одному и тому же слову можно задать вопросы что? и кто?, значит ли это что слова могут менять одушевленность? и следует ли из этого, что это должно быть отражено в падежах, расположении относительно глагола и тп?

Answer (score 2):

**Это ответы на вопросы**, заданные в комментариях

**1. Порядок слов относительно глагола, именительный падеж, одушевленность**

*Давайте за основу возьмем: мать любит дочь. кто - мать, что делает любит, любит что - дочь. Мать - именительный падеж. То есть именительный падеж имеет место быть, когда существительное употреблено до глагола и зависимых слов?*

*… одному и тому же слову можно задать вопросы что? и кто?, значит ли это что слова могут менять одушевленность? и следует ли из этого, что это должно быть отражено в падежах, расположении относительно глагола и тп?*

**Именительный падеж** — особенный. Это начальная форма, имя, название предмета. В предложении его функции известны (подлежащее, приложение к подлежащему, именная часть сказуемого). Значит, надо понимать грамматический разбор предложения, видеть эти функции.

***Мать (кто? И.п.) любит (кого? В.п.) дочь***

**Парный вариант**: *Мать (кого? В.п.) любит (кто? И.п.) дочь.* Порядок слов неестественный. Рассмотрим **такие предложения**: *Мать (В.п. беспредложный) она (И.п.) любит, но ссорится с ней постоянно. Про мать (В.п. предложный) она и не вспоминает.
В этих примерах мы видим **разную позицию** одуш. сущ. «мать» в форме В.п.*

**2. Предикативность и порядок слов**

*в русском языке не все предложения предикативные, а также есть личные, но бессубъектные и с предикативностью я не уверен, если было все предикативно, то порядок бы слов не нарушался.*

Предикативности вроде бы нет **в назывном предложении**, но это как понимать. Там один главный член совмещает в себе функции подлежащего и сказуемого. Уже то, что мы называем предмет в предложении,  говорит о том, что он там присутствует, тоже своего рода предикативность.
**Например**: *Наступила весна. Весна! Все живое радуется ее приходу*.  Или так:  *Весна. Побежали ручьи  с пригорков,  веселее щебечут птицы.* В неполных и эллиптических предложениях сказуемое восстанавливается по контексту или домысливается.

Почему мы позволяем себе **менять порядок слов?** Такая свобода — это особенность нашего языка, а основан эта возможность **на грамматических связях.** Позиция слова для грамматического разбора не является таким важным фактором, как в других языках, где ее нет или она выражена не в полной мере.

**4. О синонимии**

*…форма слов совпадает, и(!) вопросы совпадают.*

*причина синонимии не ясна: синонимия зависит от одушевленности, а в первом склонении синонимии нет, хотя, если только считать и.п. 1 склонения чистым именительным падежом, а не родительным второго склонения. 1 и 6?. чем обусловлено взаимное расположение слов(относительно глагола) и как это влияет на выбор падежа?*

Совпадают и формы слов,  и падежные вопросы. В частности **вопрос «что»** относится к И.п. и к В.п. (неодуш.).

**О синонимии окончаний.** В первом склонении **окончание Е** относится к двум падежам (*рад весне, думаю о весне*). Но они различаются по предлогу. В то же время предлоги тоже могут быть **синонимами**, например: скучаю (по чему?) по весне, приехал (когда?) по весне. *Речушка виляла, разливаясь **по весне** так, что подмывала все мосты.* Можно придумать и другие примеры. Поэтому не стоит полностью **доверяться форме.**

**5. Глагол и порядок слов**

*чем обусловлено взаимное расположение слов(относительно глагола) и как это влияет на выбор падежа?*

Взаимное расположение слов  **относительно глагола**?  Это определяется общей структурой предложения, где выражено многое. В чем-то мы свободны и меняем порядок слов, в то же время учитываем **связи слов** с  глаголом (глагольное управление). Например: *Он часто думал (о чем?) **об этой встрече*** (прямой порядок слов). ***Об этой встрече** он думал часто* (инверсия при актуальном членении).

На падеж позиция глагола не влиет. Мы можем определить падеж **по словосочетанию** даже при инверсии: *думать (о чем?) **о встрече***, П.п.

Comment: Спасибо, однако: 1. - вы добавили предлог "про мать", а я говорил, что если мать идет до глагола(без предлога), то это И.П. А если после, то это скорее всего В.П. либо акцентированная на слове конструкция, например, обращение. Мать послушала - И.П. послушала мать - В.П. и мать тут неодушевленное, либо это И.П. послушала, мать? обращение с вопросом, вопрос разворачивает значение восприятие на одушевленное и Мать становится в И.П. одушевленным, плюс добавляется запятая обращения, связанная с разрушением согласования глагола и сущ слов.

Comment: Далее, изменим окончание у глагола, не "женского рода" согласования(принадлежность). Мать послушалась, послушалась мать - получаем обратную картину. Мать что сделала? - послушалась/послушалась кто? - мать. Уже вопросы что и кто указывают на вероятную "одушевленность".

Comment: Так вот, у меня появилось предположение, что вся эта одушевленность и "род" связаны вовсе не с делением на женское и мужское в смысле пола. А по отношении с предлогами, которые не нужны, за счет существования окончания.
То есть, вот связанный вопрос: как определить род слова? Вот вы не знаете, какой род у слова или почему у слова, например, тюлень - мужской род, а у слова тень - женский?

Comment: Так вот, выбор рода и связанная с ним одушевленность/падеж(родительный или винительный) связаны с отношением слова с глаголом. Если "от чего" то это женский род - тень от дерева. Если для чего - то мужской род. Тюлень - промысловое животное, для промысла, а нерпа, например, не промысловое, а живущее непосредственно в реках, то есть промышленного производства организовано не было. Корова - та кто дает молоко, а не "тот" что нужен, чтобы получать молоко, для молока, однако бык нужен для размножения.

Comment: То есть женский род - или то от чего-то что-то исходит, а мужской - это для чего-то. То есть основа рода слова определяется предлогами от и для. Средний же род не связан с этими предлогами, но связан с вопросом "что" - то есть средний род связан с понятиями. Мать родила дочь. Дочь родилась от матери. Солнце осветило двор, во дворе светло от солнечного света - требуется больше предлогов и доп слов, вроде "свет". Мальчик рубил дерево, дерево не от мальчика, а для дома.

Comment: 2. Касательно предикативности, я говорил о выражениях, когда нет существительного/подлежащего: Леплю. Выбегаю... Касательно "Наступила весна" - тут как раз реверсивная конструкция, потому и предикативность, то есть реверсивность конструкции не "весна пришла", а "пришла весна" как раз и дает предикативность. "Весна пришла в мир" = "пришла весна" - и тут у меня есть сомнения в том, что весна является таки подлежащим из-за предикативности, так как подлежащее не является предикатом.

Comment: 4. я понимаю, что по-классике вот так, но этот подход не объясняет совпадение окончаний и как в конце концов происходит различие. Вот например, почему кофе вдруг становится мужским родом, а не средним. Пишут мол кофий, а почему кофий? а молоко - средний род, а не молокий или молок? Нет, ну просто сказать, мол так карта легла, но нет же, название дает уже понимание о том, как можно слово употреблять, то есть понимание грамматики с ним связанной и формы окончаний слов также дают понимание об использовании. Кофе и чай для бодрости, а молоко, просто напиток неопределенной направленности.

Comment: Так вот. В английском этих окончаний нет, но есть предлоги и артикли, а в русском языке прелог или отношение слова к понятию или еще какой-то категории заключено в окончании. Ну и в целом слова в русском, как я говорил, это ближе к написанию слов в английском с большой буквы - то есть названия именно, а в английском cat - это просто common nouns - общие понятия. B cat - это не кот или кошка, а кошачье(понятие средний род). То есть род в русском влияет на восприятие пола чего-то, но это скорее следствие, суть рода в отношении грамматической позиции слова в предложении/фразе.

Comment: И еще дополнительно накладывается категория одушевленности/неодушевленности отвечающая за партитивность или грамматическое позиционирования относительно других понятий. То есть род - это связь с глаголом, а "одушевленность" влияет на отношение между существительными. От сюда есть взгляд через падежи, но проблема что падежи уже выбраны, а как они выбираются? А есть взгляд через логику, но проблема в том, что часть конструкций под логику предикативов не ложится, а существует вне её. Предикативы работают только с понятиями, они не могут работать с названиями/именованиями.

Comment: 5. Наоборот, не порядок слов определяется структурой, а структура предложения определяется порядком слов - это проблема русского языка. Другой порядок - другая структура. В вашем примере проблема, что вы сохраняете предлог, используете предлог. Окончание - это уже прелог, а если вы задаете предлог, то тут можно уже таскать куски туда-сюда не меняя окончание. Однако - измените положение предлога, уберите предлог и вся структура посыпется. "Об этой встрече" - фраза держится на предлоге об.

Comment: Спасибо, однако? )) Но в языке мы имеем дело  с результатом (сложившейся формой), все глубинное понимание предмета от нас скрыто. У вас же — своеобразная творческая лаборатория, где вы реконструируете процесс создания и развития лексики и грамматики, а также сравниваете различные языки. Такой подход — не для всех native Russian speaker, так что непонимание с их стороны я вам гарантирую)).   Но для тех, кто хочет понять и почувствовать язык где-то на уровне подсознания,  ваши мысли, безусловно, очень интересны.

Comment: Ну скрыто да, потому что не отрывали, изучали предмет, а внутри не смотрели. То есть такие исследования были в начале 20 века, когда какие-то новые формы пытались изобрести, обэрриуты всякие и прочие авангардисты. А сейчас все пытаются скопировать логику и слова английского, свой язык вообще не интересует. С другой стороны смысл в чём. Не в том, чтобы свой язык приравнять к другому и подтянуть нормы и правила под чужую языковую систему, а в том, чтобы найти пересечения или различие в основе и понять как вообще устроена РЕЧЬ, если РЕЧЬ - это совокупность разных языковых систем их выражений.